System freezes on ASUS TUF 506 laptop with Ubuntu 24.04
I am experiencing a critical system stability issue on Ubuntu that does not occur on Windows 10 or on the previous Ubuntu version (21.04).
I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04, but suddenly my Ubuntu freezes.
Hardware details:

Laptop model: ASUS TUF 506
Operating systems: Dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10
Kernel version: 6.8.0-50-generic

The system completely freezes.

The laptop becomes entirely unresponsive.
No keyboard or mouse input works.
The only option is to force shutdown using the power button.

Fan behavior:

All laptop fans activate simultaneously.
Fans run at maximum speed during the freeze.
This occurs suddenly and unexpectedly.

Environment:

No such issues were observed on the previous Ubuntu 21.04 version.
Windows 10 operates normally with no problems.

